# Mysql : Using derived table in subquery

Tags: mysql

In my (very simplified) schema, i have 3 tables : offers, attributes, attributes_offers.

I want to use subquery from a derived table, in this query :

```
SELECT
    o.offer_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(attr.attribute_code,'-',attr.value_id,'-',attr.value_value) SEPARATOR ';') AS attributes,
    (SELECT attr.value_id FROM attr WHERE attribute_code = 'area') AS area_id,
    (SELECT attr.value_id FROM attr WHERE attribute_code = 'category') AS category_id
FROM   offers o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT offer_id,attribute_code,value_id,value_value
    FROM   attributes_offers ao
    INNER JOIN attributes att USING (attribute_code) 
) AS attr ON attr.offer_id = o.offer_id
```

But MySql answers me : `Table 'attr' doesn't exist`.

Group_concat works well.

Is there a way to use my derived table attr in select subquery?

Comment: Make a different alias name for table `attr`. And change alias name `attr` to any other name for inner join query.

Answer (score 1):

it's normal because the table 'attr' and the select you are trying to use on it are in different blocks... see it this way, the Select you are trying to do is in a box and you can't see what's outside. try this

```
SELECT
    o.offer_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(attr.attribute_code,'-',attr.value_id,'-',attr.value_value) SEPARATOR ';') AS attributes,
   attr.value_id AS area_id,
    attr.value_id AS category_id
FROM   offers o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT offer_id,attribute_code,value_id,value_value
    FROM   attributes_offers ao
    INNER JOIN attributes att USING (attribute_code) 
) AS attr ON attr.offer_id = o.offer_id
```

and if you wana fetch all the value_id try to do it in another query because the one you r trying to do is simply not gonna work

Comment: In fact, that's what i want to do, get some value_id in different column, depending of attribute_code. What's the good way to do this?

Comment: You can always add the "WHERE" block and add a condition on the attribute_code. Remember this next time when you query the database for one or more lines in each line, the attribute has one value, there is no way u can get more than one value unless you wana use Object database wich is another subject.